# Error in Wordpress - elementor after ugrading PHP 7.4

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor, litespeed, php-7.4

After upgrading to PHP 7.4, elemntor started giving error

url: [www.aldon.ltd/](http://www.aldon.ltd/)
Cloud Service: GCP
Server: Openlitespeed Wordpress
Linux: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

```
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/controls-stack.php on line 1449
```

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/controls-stack.php on line 1451

Except this notice shown at the top of webpage, all other functions are working as expected.

Code causing error
/**
* End controls section.
*
* Used to close an existing open controls section. When you use this method
* it stops adding new controls to this section.
*
* This method should be used inside `_register_controls()`.
*
* @since 1.4.0
* @access public
*/
Public function end_controls_section() {
$stack_name = $this->get_name();

```
            // Save the current section for the action.
            $current_section = $this->current_section;
            $section_id = $current_section['section'];
            $args = [
                    'tab' => $current_section['tab'],
            ];
```

Error Log at /usr/local/lsws/logs/error.log

PHP Notice: wp_deregister_script was called **incorrectorrectly**. Do not deregister the `jquery-core` script in the administration area. To target the front-end theme, use the wp_enqueue_scrip>
PHP Notice: /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/controls-stack.php on line 1449
PHP Notice: /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/controls-stack.php on line 1451

Comment: Please provide code from `controls-stack.php` that demonstrates the problem. From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/26622796).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it for a temporary solution. Changing line no. 1204 from

```
if ( $dynamic_property ) ) {
```

to

```
if ( $dynamic_property && isset($settings[ $control_name ][ $dynamic_property ]) ) {
```